# Using ArrayAdapter means No more Using Loop?

Tags: arrays, for-loop, listview, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

So I have recently studied about ArrayAdapter and ListView but when I am not using both but using LinearLayout I am putting a for loop but when I use ListView the code is entirely different and it looks like that I am not using for loop anymore. I want to know ListView does not require loops? if data is stored in Arraylist?

**Case 1: Using LinearLayout**

```
ArrayList<String> words= new ArrayList<String>();

words.add(0, "one");
words.add(1, "two");
words.add(2, "three");
words.add(3, "four")


LinearLayout rootView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootView);


for (int index= 0; index < 3; index++) {
                /*TextView wordView = new TextView(this);
                wordView.setText(words.get(index));
                rootView.addView(wordView);


Case 2: When using  listview + arrayadapter 

ArrayList<String> words= new ArrayList<String>();

words.add(0, "one");
words.add(1, "two");
words.add(2, "three");
words.add(3, "four");


ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, words);

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

listView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
```

---

**So  I want to know why there is no loop statement in ArrayAdapter and ListView.**

Answer (score 0):

The adapter (of the ListView) extracts the correct data from the data object (in this case the ArrayList) and assigns this data to the views in the row of the `ListView`

An adapter manages the data model and adapts it to the individual entries in the widget. An adapter extends the BaseAdapter class.

For more info you may look here: https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html
or the official Android Docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView

Comment: Thanks for answer. But my question still stands does using listview+arrayadapter eliminates the need of a loop?

Comment: Yes. No need of loop. The array adapter extracts all the values one by one

Comment: What if the Adapter iterates more than it should? Like 45 times when the array only has 6 values. What could be the cause of this?

Comment: The implementation of array adapter has a length (similar name) function that you implement. Internally the logic is done so that it does not exceed the limit